# Does srand() in C produce a different number set than Python's randint() when they use the same seed?

Tags: python, c

If I generate a random set of numbers using C's srand(), then generate a random set of numbers using Python's randint(), both with the same seed, will they produce the same set of random numbers?

Comment: depends on the implementation, obviously. Why don't you try it and see?  My guess would be no, but I'm not looking any deeper into it.

Comment: 1. Check the implementation. 2. You are generating random numbers. Why do you care if they are the same or not? I think it is kinda the opposite of "randomness".

Comment: @simre Repeatable *pseudo random* sequences can be useful for certain use cases…

Comment: @deceze I agree, in the same program. But he is mixing C and python. So in 2 totally different language (I know python is in C), you can't trust that they will be the same. And if you do, it is a punch in the face when they don't. And probably they won't be the same all the time.... Also for portability this assumption is a killer... You want 2 random number generators to generate the same thing. This is against randomness...

Comment: There is no guarantee that they will be the same. So no.

Comment: From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), "Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator." What does the documentation on your c implementation say it uses?

Comment: To get the same sequence, you have to implement the PRNG yourself for both. This requires some care in the implementations due to different numeric data types and different corner case behavior of certain operators. You can also implement one in C and call the same one from Python.

Comment: the C standard says nothing specifically about [rand() implementation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.10.2.1). Even `RAND_MAX` varies between implementations so obviously the same sequence can't be assured